# .htaccess remove string at the end of url

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Suppose I have urls like these:

```
/toys/id-2005200520056-what-ever-toy-name
```

I would like to only keep the id part:

```
/toys/id-2005200520056
```

The id always has 13 digits.

This is what I tried but it's not working.

```
RewriteRule ^(id-[0-9]{13}) $1 [L]
```

Can someone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file? Ordinarily, when you "remove" part of a URL you need to trigger an external "redirect", yet you appear to be rewriting the URL instead? Is that intentional? Presumably, you have other directives - please include the entire contents of your `.htaccess` file - conflicts with existing directives is a common problem.

Comment: The caret causes it to only match `id-` at the start of a path.  If you're looking for `/toys/id-` then the `id-` is not at the start of the path so it won't match.

Comment: @tetech That depends on where the `.htaccess` file is located - which hasn't been stated.

Comment: @MrWhite Agreed.